# 64-bit integer to double collision

Tags: c++, c, double

I'm looking at a JSON validation library on GitHub that uses `double` for all numeric comparisons (i.e. it pulls the numbers out of the json as `double` before comparing to the schema, which is also pulled out as `double`).

`double` has a finite number of states, just like `uint64_t` which means "collisions" must exist - i.e. two distinct `uint64_t` that map to the exact same double.

My question is: How can I find two discrete integers that map to the same double such that I can prove to the GitHub contributor that it is not safe to cast 64-bit integers to double?

Or am I wrong and using double is perfect safe?

Comment: `1` Understand the specification of `double` (mantissa is 53 bits including the hidden bit) `2` Only ask if you're still stuck...

Comment: How did you get to the assumption that collisions must exist?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `double` is 64-bit, `uint64_t` is 64-bit, but double can represent integers in a much bigger range than `uint64_t`, therefore collisions must exist

Comment: @user202729 I did, and I was unable to find any examples of a collision or how to find one. Do you have any specific terms you recommend for Google?

Comment: "javascript number representation" and "ieee 754 binary64 standard" and some logical thinking. (which two `uint64_t` shares the first 53 most significant bits?)

Comment: Ah, so basically any integer bigger than `2^53` will cause a double collision

Answer (score 3):

As @user202729 pointed out, as long as the two integers share the same fractional bits, it will cause a double collision:

Example collision:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  uint64_t x = 99999999999999997;
  uint64_t y = 99999999999999999;
  double a = x;
  double b = y;
  cout << to_string(x == y) << " " << to_string(a == b) << endl;
}
```

Output: `0 1`

Comment: Indeed. This is why "good" libraries will only switch to floating-point when they find that they need to. Ultimately, though, any non-bignum-powered library will fail eventually because [JSON doesn't specify maximum precision or range for the _number_ production](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). As such, they all tend to make compromises to varying degrees, based on practicalities. (You may wish to add this detail to your answer.)